# How can I delete all messages from a certain address from the mailqueue?

Tags: email, postfix

We have a lot of messages in the mail queue from a certain address. I want to delete the lot of them. I've found ways to delete by subject line, but I want to search by From address, and that seems to be a lot trickier. (Note: these are mainly outgoing messages.)

Some Googling has found me this command on [HowToForge](http://www.howtoforge.com/delete-mails-to-or-from-a-specific-email-address-from-postfix-mail-queue), but there's no explanation of what it does.

```
postqueue -p | tail -n +2 | awk 'BEGIN { RS = "" } / spammer@example\.net/ { print $1 }' | tr -d '*!' | postsuper -d -
```

I was trying to use mailqueuemng, but didn't get very far (it doesn't have a --help, for one thing).

Comment: Are you using Postfix or qmail (or something else such as Exim)?  You have tagged the question as qmail but the command snippet you included is for Postfix.

Comment: Sorry, @Ladadadada. It is actually Postfix. I got confused, because we appear to also have qmail installed, and I believe the e-mail files themselves are stored in a directory called qmail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pipeline can be analyzed step by step to see what it does.  Try running each command in sequence until you understand them all:

```
postqueue -p
```

print the queue

```
postqueue -p | tail -n +2
```

get rid of the first couple lines

```
postqueue -p | tail -n +2 | awk 'BEGIN { RS = "" } / spammer@example\.net/ { print $1 }'
```

search for any lines with spammer@example.net; print the first field of those lines.

```
postqueue -p | tail -n +2 | awk 'BEGIN { RS = "" } / spammer@example\.net/ { print $1 }' | tr -d '*!'
```

get rid of any `*!`

This will output a bunch of queue ids.

```
postqueue -p | tail -n +2 | awk 'BEGIN { RS = "" } / spammer@example\.net/ { print $1 }' | tr -d '*!' | postsuper -d -
```

The final command tells postfix to delete those queue ids.

Read The Fine Man pages on `postqueue`, `tail`, `tr`, and `postsuper`.  Awk is a more complicated, it's its own little language.  you'll need a bit more than a man page to understand its complexity, although in my experience 99% of the awk usage is much like that particular one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to add an answer to an already answered question.

This is for people who have to do this on a daily basis (clients facing spam campaigns).

There's a guy who wrote "pymailq", a tool that can help dealing with this.

I've also forked this tool and added compatibility with zimbra and a few additional features.

Here's the [original repo](https://github.com/outini/pymailq)

Here's [my fork](https://github.com/moebiuseye/pymailq)

Installation goes like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/moebiuseye/pymailq.git
cd pymailq
git checkout dev

virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate

python ./setup.py install
pqshell
```