# Block outgoing emails from Postfix from non-existent users

Tags: postfix, spam

I'm getting spam sent through my server. The sender names are always random, but always in the form `randomname@mydomain.com`.

I've tried adding `reject_unlisted_senders` to the `smtpd_sender_restrictions` directive, but it doesn't work -- the emails are somehow being queued without being caught by smtpd.

Is there any other point at which I can filter these messages out of the queue? One person has suggested using postqueue to remove unwanted messages, but I'd presumably have to run that every minute, and even then probably wouldn't catch these messages, unless I'm misunderstanding how this works?

Alternatively, are there any common ways that emails might be getting into the queue without passing through smtpd which I could try to prevent, or is there any way to track how these messages are getting to the queue without passing through the smtpd sender checks?

Example email:

```
Return-Path: <adwoadanso@mydomain.co.nz>
Received: from myotherdomain.co.nz (www.mydomain.co.nz [49.50.242.200])
    (using TLSv1 with cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits))
    (No client certificate requested)
    by mtaig-aaf04.mx.aol.com (Internet Inbound) with ESMTPS id 81DBE7000008D;
    Thu, 13 Aug 2015 07:51:31 -0400 (EDT)
X-No-Relay: not in my network
X-No-Relay: not in my network
X-No-Relay: not in my network
X-No-Relay: not in my network
X-No-Relay: not in my network
X-No-Relay: not in my network
X-No-Relay: not in my network
X-No-Relay: not in my network
X-No-Relay: not in my network
X-No-Relay: not in my network
X-No-Relay: not in my network
X-No-Relay: not in my network
X-No-Relay: not in my network
X-No-Relay: not in my network
X-No-Relay: not in my network
X-No-Relay: not in my network
X-No-Relay: not in my network
X-No-Relay: not in my network
X-No-Relay: not in my network
X-No-Relay: not in my network
Received: from mydomain.co.nz (unknown [180.251.148.71])
    by myotherdomain.co.nz (Postfix) with ESMTPA id 6BCD5277BF;
    Thu, 13 Aug 2015 23:51:07 +1200 (NZST)
Subject: From:  Adwoa Danso
From: adwoa danso <adwoadanso@mydomain.co.nz>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary=Apple-Mail-A9BD329F-7B73-20AE-D05D-EE4BF9644759
X-Mailer: iPhone Mail (12D508)
Message-Id: <9a19c53ef906$68de95ee$d399e20f$@mydomain.co.nz>
Date: Wed, 13 Aug 2015 12:51:07 +0000
To: redacted@gmail.com, redacted@gmail.com, redacted@hotmail.com, redacted@yahoo.com, redacted@aol.com, redacted@monsoon.co.uk, redacted@yahoo.com, redacted@aol.com, redacted@mail.com, redacted@hays.com, redacted@yahoo.com, redacted@focusforce.com, redacted@focusforce.net, redacted@actionchapel.org.uk, redacted@yahoo.co.uk, redacted@computerfutures.com, redacted@gmail.com, redacted@focus-it-uk.com, redacted@focus-it-uk.com, redacted@sbfa.co.uk
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Mime-Version: 1.0 (1.0)
x-aol-global-disposition: G
Authentication-Results: mx.aol.com;
    spf=pass (aol.com: the domain mydomain.co.nz reports 49.50.242.200 as a permitted sender.) smtp.mailfrom=mydomain.co.nz;
x-aol-sid: 3039ac1a7f5a55cc84c22b21
X-AOL-IP: 49.50.242.200
X-AOL-SPF: domain : mydomain.co.nz SPF : pass
```

postconf -n:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
disable_vrfy_command = yes
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 20480000
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain
myhostname = mydomain.co.nz
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128 49.50.242.200/32 49.50.242.201/32 49.50.242.202/32
mynetworks_style = host
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
non_smtpd_milters = , inet:127.0.0.1:12768
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.8.14/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.8.14/samples
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/sdd_transport_maps
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_send_xforward_command = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net
smtpd_milters = , inet:127.0.0.1:12768
smtpd_proxy_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, check_client_access pcre:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/no_relay.re, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unlisted_sender, check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_client_access pcre:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/non_auth.re
smtpd_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix_default.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
transport_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
virtual_gid_maps = static:31
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/qmail/mailnames
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
virtual_mailbox_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
virtual_transport = plesk_virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:30
```

Example email from non-existent user:

```
Aug 20 04:03:23 myuser postfix/qmgr[6151]: 955692790A: from=<franzadilazard@mydomain.co.nz>, size=2571, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Aug 20 04:04:24 myuser postfix/smtp[5810]: 955692790A: to=<>, relay=none, delay=267202, delays=267141/0.01/61/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alpha17.com[54.174.31.254]:25: Connection timed out)
Aug 20 05:13:23 myuser postfix/qmgr[6151]: 955692790A: from=<franzadilazard@mydomain.co.nz>, size=2571, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Aug 20 05:14:25 myuser postfix/smtp[7148]: 955692790A: to=<[redacted@spamrecipient.com]>, relay=none, delay=271402, delays=271341/0.01/61/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alpha17.com[54.174.31.254]:25: Connection timed out)
Aug 20 06:23:23 myuser postfix/qmgr[6151]: 955692790A: from=<franzadilazard@mydomain.co.nz>, size=2571, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Aug 20 06:24:23 myuser postfix/smtp[9472]: 955692790A: to=<[redacted@spamrecipient.com]>, relay=none, delay=275600, delays=275540/0.01/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alpha17.com[54.174.31.254]:25: Connection timed out)
Aug 20 07:33:23 myuser postfix/qmgr[6151]: 955692790A: from=<franzadilazard@mydomain.co.nz>, size=2571, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Aug 20 07:34:24 myuser postfix/smtp[11376]: 955692790A: to=<[redacted@spamrecipient.com]>, relay=none, delay=279802, delays=279741/0.01/61/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alpha17.com[54.174.31.254]:25: Connection timed out)
Aug 20 08:43:23 myuser postfix/qmgr[6151]: 955692790A: from=<franzadilazard@mydomain.co.nz>, size=2571, nrcpt=20 (queue active)
Aug 20 08:44:24 myuser postfix/smtp[13132]: 955692790A: to=<[redacted@spamrecipient.com]>, relay=none, delay=284002, delays=283941/0.01/61/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alpha17.com[54.208.74.215]:25: Connection timed out)
```

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that question in my opinion, though I've edited my question to contain some of the troubleshooting in that post. The emails are being sent via my server, and they are going through postfix -- if anyone knows how to reject all senders and only allow a certain few, that would be fantastic!

Comment: @JeremyWarne Second link looks like the fix, if it isn't a spambot on your server.

Comment: please provide `postconf -n`

Comment: @BillThor I've made the change recommended in that link, and these messages are still being sent. Edited original question with postconf and log entries.

Comment: Post complete maillog entry e.g. `grep BA1922790B /var/log/mail.log`

Comment: And the reason why it's not working because you put `reject_unlisted_sender` after `permit_sasl_authenticated`. Put the restriction in front of others.

Comment: I changed the order of the restriction, putting reject_unlisted_sender first; still getting the same problems. Editing post to add complete maillog entry

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [normal mail flow](http://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html) inside of postfix when you *relaying* email.

```
Client --- smtpd (receive) --- Queue Manager --- smtp (delivery)
```

Parameter `reject_unlisted_sender` only help you block message in `smtpd` when postfix receiving email from <s>client</s> spammer. From the log you attached above, looks like the message **already** in queue, so the rejection won't happen. This parameter will kick in when <s>client</s> spammer relay email  with fake email address.

The solution is **remove email from postfix queue**. See this thread for example: [How can I delete all messages from a certain address from the mailqueue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/525396/how-can-i-delete-all-messages-from-a-certain-address-from-the-mailqueue/). See also [man 1 postsuper](http://www.postfix.org/postsuper.1.html) and [man 1 postqueue](http://www.postfix.org/postqueue.1.html).